# Embedding SideDrawer in NativeScript with Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am developing mobile app by using nativescript with angular. I want to use side drawer in my application. I found some samples online. Those all are for the whole application. I want to exclude Side Drawer for one module such as login module. If you have some experiences with that, please share me.

Thanks & Best Regards,
Zaw Zaw Naing

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the whole-app examples and create your sidedrawer as a root component. Then in pages where you need to hide the sidedrawer (e.g. like login page), you could get the reference and disable the drawer interaction  (this way make it inaccessible). Example of the above [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.component.ts#L43-L44)

TypeScript

```
import { getRootView } from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";

// use this in ngAfterViewInit 
// example: https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.component.ts#L43-L44
this.drawer = <RadSideDrawer>getRootView();
this.drawer.gesturesEnabled = false;
```